# How to avoid KeyError without using try/except?

Tags: python

In the following code snippet:

```
for record in records:    
  max = record.get_values()['max']
```

In this code, I am getting max value from record. "records" is a generator object here. The problem is, in some cases max field won't be present. So I am getting KeyError in those cases. I want to assign `max = 0` if max isn't present in record. So far I have come with this solution:

```
try:    
  max = record.get_values()['max']
except:
  max = 0
```

But I want to avoid using try-except in this case as there are many more lines like this and it will make my code look messy. How can I achieve the same functionality without using try-except or long lines of code? It will be preferable if this can be done in a single line of code.

Comment: If `record.get_values()` returns a dictionary then you could use `max = record.get_values().get("max", 0)`

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `get()` to avoid key error. it will return `None` for missing `key`: if `record.get_values()` returns a `dict` use:

```
for record in records:    
  max = record.get_values().get('max')


# will return **None** for missing key by default, you can add a default value if needed.
```

a simple example is:

```
emp_dict = {'Name': 'Pankaj', 'ID': 1}

emp_id = emp_dict.get('ID')
emp_role = emp_dict.get('Role')
emp_salary = emp_dict.get('Salary', 0)

print(f'Employee[ID:{emp_id}, Role:{emp_role}, Salary:{emp_salary}]')

# Output: Employee[ID:1, Role:None, Salary:0]
```

Comment: Better is to supply a default in the `get()` call, as already commented.

Comment: `.get` takes a second argument to return if the key isn't present.

Comment: default value is optional. you can mention a default value as your wish but by default it will return `None`. check here if needed https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the key "max" exists in the dictionary using a ternary operator.

```
max = record.get_values()["max"] if "max" in record.get_values().keys() else 0
```